# Delay in traveling

Tags: visas, usa

Having a (B1/B2) US visa-with a virgin passport,  and not using it (traveling) at all for about a year,does this make the visa invalid, or is it still safe for the individual to travel giving the circumstance?

Comment: How did the visa get onto your virgin passport?

Answer (score 1):

How much you use the visa doesn't matter. As long as it's valid (generally that means it has not expired and allows multiple re-entries) then you can travel.